# Can't connect to VPN after Windows password expired

Tags: windows-xp, passwords, vpn

I have remote access to my company network. My Windows password was set to expire on January 1st and I didn't change it.

Now I can log on in Windows, but after trying to connect to the VPN with my smartcard, it says that I'm connected but in fact I'm not because I can't access the intranet or any files.

I guess it has something to do with my expired password. Any ideas how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Create a new user?

Comment: Does your company have an IT department? You might try asking them. This question is off-topic for a programming Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

after etablishing the VPN connection to your company, hit ctrl + alt + del and choose 'change password' 
afterwards the network/servers have automatically your new passwort and you should have access again.
this is because the company network recognizes your expired Password and don't allow you access to the Ressources.